# Drupal: wrapping blocks together

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

can I group blocks in Drupal 6 ?
I need to wrap two adjacent blocks in a single  parent element in my page.

thanks

Comment: In drupal 7, you can now use blockgroups to group blocks together. Really new module but it makes things a lot easier: http://drupal.org/project/blockgroup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a region that has the wrapping markup you need, or you can create a theme function to do it for you. There are several other ways that you can use, as Drupal has a very flexible theming system, but there's not a setting etc. to let you do it from the UI.

Comment: I second building a new region into the theme. That seems like what regions were made for.